# how to connect Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client VPN using batch script or shell script in windows

Tags: networking, vpn, powershell, batch, cisco-vpn-client

I am using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client in win server 2008 R2 standard and I want to run it using script daily on 10:00PM and close it on 10:30PM after some transaction done.
How can I run Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client VPN using cmd automatically...

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by scheduling jobs through batch files to invoke the AnyConnect executable *vpncli.exe*. Getting familiarized with *vpncli.exe* on what parameters it takes will be helpful. Just invoke it via cmd prompt passing the *help* argument.

- For the connection attempt, necessary information (i.e., tunnel group, credentials etc.,) required should be present in a text file and passed as an input to *vpncli.exe*. This [SO post](https://superuser.com/q/1103953/68120) should be helpful.
- To disconnect, just invoke the executable passing the *disconnect* argument.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh the SO post helped me.

Comment: Glad I was helpful.